# RubyCocoa segmentation fault on OS X 10.11

Tags: ruby, macos

In the OS X 10.11 GM (and earlier betas), I can't seem to use RubyCocoa in my Ruby scripts.

The fault occurs as soon as I try to import the program
`require 'osx/cocoa'`

I get this rather lengthy response thrown back at me:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rubycocoa.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0011 p:-17523712989436 s:0052 e:000051 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0010 p:---- s:0050 e:000049 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0115 s:0046 e:000045 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0008 p:0007 s:0036 e:000035 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/osx/foundation.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0034 e:000033 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0115 s:0030 e:000029 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0005 p:0007 s:0020 e:000019 TOP    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/osx/cocoa.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0004 p:---- s:0018 e:000017 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0115 s:0014 e:000013 METHOD /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0002 p:0007 s:0004 E:001138 EVAL   Untitled.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000058 TOP    [FINISH]

Untitled.rb:1:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/osx/cocoa.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/osx/foundation.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: Untitled.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rbconfig.rb
    4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    6 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    8 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
    9 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   10 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   11 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   12 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   13 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   14 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   15 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   16 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Run Command: line 1:  6066 Abort trap: 6           ruby "$1" "${@:3}"
```

Can anyone please help in working out where I even begin with this? The new SIP in OS X makes it difficult to poke around the framework, and I'd like to avoid doing so, to ensure my scripts will run on any client machines.